# Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 community edition installation errors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to install visual studio 2015 and it's coming back with these errors:

- Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2015 -> Fatal Error
- Microsoft NuGet - Visual Studio 2015 -> Package Failed
- Microsoft Visual Studio Connected Services -> Packages Failed
- Azure AD Authentication Connected Services -> Packages Failed
- Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Connected Service -> Package Failed
- Microsoft Azure Storeage Connected Service -> Packages Failed
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Office365 -> Package Failed

I've googled this and seen that this is already a question here with a solution,
[Multiple Errors Installing Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855177/multiple-errors-installing-visual-studio-2015-community-edition). I'm only asking another question because I couldn't post mine on the original one.

The soultion states that the c++ redistributable must be repaired because they are getting the 64 and 32 bit dlls mixed up. So I repaired them but it still installs the dlls to the wrong folder and I thought that maybe if I move them myself that would do the trick, but the visual studio installer seems to install them again anyway undoing my changes.

Does anyone have any other suggestions to make on how to get around this problem?

Comment: Just realized that on a 64-bit machine the "System32" is for 64-bit related stuff and the "SysWOW64" is for 32-bit related stuff... nice one microsoft! That is why I thought the installers were putting the dlls in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Working!
I 've tried all the workarounds without success and what finally do the trick was to uninstall all visual studios and all Microsoft Visual C++ XXX Redistributable x86 and x64 versions.
Then, run the Visual Stuido installer again.

Hope it helps!