# Visual Studio 2015 Team Explorer Fatal Error during installation

Tags: visual-studio, fatal-error, team-explorer

I'm having problems installing VS2015 Professional with Update 1.

These are the solutions I've tried.

1. Reinstallation from the ISO
2. Remove all VS packages from Programs and Features
3. Tried the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855177/multiple-errors-installing-visual-studio-2015-community-edition/33881460#33881460)

Here are the logs from the installation (scroll to the bottom)
http://chopapp.com/#54nqprgr

Answer (score -1):

turn on Windows Update in Services