# Error Installing Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 1 with Team Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am having the same problem everyone else is when installing Visual Studio 2015 with Update 1. It is failing on the Team Explorer install and as far as I can tell it is being caused by the same error outlined in this question ([Multiple Errors Installing Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855177/multiple-errors-installing-visual-studio-2015-community-edition/34008086)). I have tried the steps explained in the answers to that question, including the answer that is in Russian. However, the installation is still failing at the same point. I am at my wits end now and out of ideas to try.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This thread solved it for me: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f3768c09-6776-4b68-a5ae-52885e782fa0/vs-2015-enterprise-reinstall-multiple-errors-starting-with-team-explorer-fatal-error

Comment: Please check this thread. The issue is sovled and root cause identified. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855177/multiple-errors-installing-visual-studio-2015-community-edition/46417198#46417198

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Well I ended up opening a technical support case with microsoft to resolve my issue. They found the issue below in my log files:

## The actual problem

> During the VS 2015 install, there are couple of VSIX packages
>   installed via custom action.  For example: TeamExplorer.vsix is
>   executed via custom action and TeamExplorer.vsix package installs the
>   Team Explorer binaries
>
> we found that all the VSIX packages fail to install. As a result, VS
>   fails to install. According to the bundle log:
>
> [2284:0D4C][2016-01-20T12:53:42]i301: Applying execute package:
>   nugetvs, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package
>   Cache{4BE72B6B-1E33-3D51-82CE-AE9702AA2664}v3.3.0.167\packages\WPT\NuGetVisualStudio14.msi,
>   arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7"'
>   [29A0:2B30][2016-01-20T12:54:11]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package
>   (nugetvs) failed: Error Message Id: 1722 ErrorMessage: There is a
>   problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of
>   the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel
>   or package vendor.   [2284:0D4C][2016-01-20T12:54:12]e000: Error
>   0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
>   [2284:0D4C][2016-01-20T12:54:12]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to
>   execute MSI package. [29A0:2B30][2016-01-20T12:54:12]e000: Error
>   0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
>
> As per the VSIX logs, we found the below stack for most the of VSIX
>   packages failure (for example
>   VSIXInstaller_43a2c244-da76-4e26-b086-0341b7e77c1f.log ):
>
> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.IInstallableExtension.get_InvalidCertificateInformation()'.
>   at VSIXInstaller.App.LogSignatureDetails(IExtension extension)    at
>   VSIXInstaller.App.LogExtensionDetails(IExtension extension)    at
>   VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall(Boolean isRepairSupported)    at
>   VSIXInstaller.App.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
>
> **we found a similar Bug 177561:Slipstream build fails to patch (RTM)
>   MSIs that are already installed by another (smaller) bundle and it’s
>   still in active state. I’ll check with my productive group and get
>   back to you.**

As you can see, this is a known issue with Microsoft. I asked for alternate suggestions to get this installed and the support rep asked me to do a clean install with the **non-update 1 version of VS Enterprise 2015**. I follow the instructions below to perform a clean install and it worked.

## The actual solution

1. Uninstall Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise  from Programs and Features

   - *I also uninstalled the 2015 C++ runtimes and Entity Framework 2015 libraries as well*
2. Reboot machine if prompted
3. Rename or delete folders-

   - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0
   - C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0
   - C:\users\*user*\Documents\Visual Studio 2015
   - C:\users\*user*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0
   - C:\users\*user*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0
   - C:\users\*user*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0
4. Go to the registry editor (start >> run >> regedit) and remove/rename the following registries-

   - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0
   - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0
   - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0
   - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config
5. close all your Visual Studio instances
6. download **Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise RTM** *not update 1*
7. Extract the .iso file by using an extraction tool, such as WinRar.
8. Clear %temp% before going to start Visual Studio 2015 installation
9. Install Visual Studio 2015 using this extracted setup installer

And... tada, the installation was finally successful! I hope this helps others that have a similar issue that isn't resolved by repairing the C++ runtimes alone.

Once RTM was installed successfully I was able to run the Update 1 installer and update successfully. Since then, I have also installed Update 2 with no issues.

Comment: I can't upvote myself but +1 to me for spending a support ticket to get this resolved!

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the community edition, and the other question's answers didn't work for me, so I'll try this tonight!

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! After way too much time this fixed it for me.

Comment: Now there's 2015-update-1 everywhere, it's not that easy to find a 2015-rtm download links. But they still seem to be available at microsoft sites, just not advertised. I found a bunch of links at https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2015/07/21/visual-studio-2015-iso-download-links-official-directoffline-links/, for example [vs2015pro direct Microsoft link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/8/9/589A8843-BA4D-4E63-BCB2-B2380E5556FD/vs2015.pro_enu.iso)

Comment: Any particular reason to 'extract' the ISO vs just mounting it?

Comment: That was just what the support rep suggested. I don't think there really is any reason to extract the iso other than to rule out any mounting issues during the installation.

Comment: I was able to solve my issue following the steps at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f3768c09-6776-4b68-a5ae-52885e782fa0/vs-2015-enterprise-reinstall-multiple-errors-starting-with-team-explorer-fatal-error

Comment: @fcm yes, the reason as I observed without extracting is that installation uses whatever file is available, but after extracting installation downloads similar package (maybe of diff version).

Answer (score 12):

To make it easier, here is a batch file to do the clean up before installing Visual Studio 2015.

```
@echo.
@echo This will remove all files, directories and registry keys about VISUAL STUDIO 2015
@echo.
@pause

rd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0" /S
rd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0" /S
rd "C:%homepath%\Documents\Visual Studio 2015" /S
rd "C:%homepath%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" /S
rd "C:%homepath%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" /S
rd "C:%homepath%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0" /S

@echo.
@echo Removing Registry Keys
@pause

REG DELETE HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0
REG DELETE HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0
REG DELETE HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0
REG DELETE HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config

@echo.
@echo. FINISHED!
@pause
```

Just copy and paste it in a .bat files

Answer (score 5):

Success! Easy to try, anyway.

I had similar problems and tried re-installing several times, but no joy. I was looking at installing individual packages from the ISO - not happy at all.

I finally got it to "install" by simply selecting "repair" rather than "uninstall" in control panel / programs. It took quite a while to do the "repair" though. In the end it is installed and working.

This may help some.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, David. I'm not 100% sure now, but I believe I actually had to do a repair after the install as well. However, if I remember correctly, I had to do so because of the VC++ runtime issue outlined in the other question. I didn't include it in my answer since it was actually a separate issue.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue with VS2015 Update 3. Repairing it doesn't fix the failed installation.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Brian.

I agree.

The only solution for me was to completely remove EVERY program on my system that had "2015" in its program name (using the terrific Revo Uninstaller and running under "Quick Uninstall" after selecting each program in the listing.
That does a "bulk" uninstall so you do not have to do it manually one after the other). This too AGES. (Make sure each program relates to Visual Studio though...all mine did.)

I then went through each step outlined in Brian Stewart's answer on Jan 28th at 19:00. I chose to install EVERYTHING in the Visual Studio installation (may as well just in case of need!) At the end of the install I found I had 77 programs now installed with the number "2015" in the program name.

Note that after the completion of the Install from the downloaded "ISO" (run under "Admin" authority) there was one final re-run of the Install again from the ISO (using "Repair" this time) to finally fix a "NuGet" package failure.
After that all was 100% correct. (With no need to re-install the C++ libraries)

I then performed a shutdown and restart and tested Visual Studio, loading a project I had previously created. (If you do not have one, then just try creating a project).

You may get errors associated with settings files missing, such as:
Page '3185ed96-1cbd-4381-a439-636973542e50' not found.

You must then exit Visual Studio and perform these commands from a CMD prompt (elevated to Administrator) in order. After each Visual Objects IDE opens up, close it and run the next command.

1.devenv.exe /safemode

2.devenv.exe /resetskippkgs

3.devenv.exe /installvstemplates

4.devenv.exe /resetsettings

5.devenv.exe /resetuserdata

Then perform a final shutdown/start-up and everything should work fine.

So after all this, I finally performed an "image" backup of my whole system so that if needs be I can at least re-install my system with Visual Studio correctly installed.

Brickbats to Microsoft for making installation of Visual Studio so painful.
After years of paying good dollars for this great programming environment I was a little annoyed that now it is free to everyone, but I guess Microsoft is making us pay in some way with our patience. LOL  :-)

It was a very long and tedious procedure, but everything now installed without error.

Thanks so much to Brian Stewart for pointing us all in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out Revo Uninstaller. this completely resolved my problems!

Answer (score 3):

After you've done what [Brian Swart has outlined](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35069784), here's the link to the VS 2015 Community RTM edition iso.

http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/B/C/0BC321A4-013F-479C-84E6-4A2F90B11269/vs2015.com_enu.iso

*(I would put this in a comment after quetzalcoatl's Mar 14 [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889317/error-installing-visual-studio-2015-enterprise-update-1-with-team-explorer#comment59646331_35069784) but I can't comment without 50 reputation.  And this entry is admittedly a stupid "answer", which means that I will probably get downvoted and will get no closer to being able to put appropriate text in a comment instead of in answer. Ridiculous system they've got here.)*

Comment: Thank you. I have been looking for this iso for quite some time now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same "Team Explorer" error installing Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 2 on a Win 10 (64b Enterprise) PC. Tried a Repair install a few times which did not work.
What worked:
- uninstalled Visual Studio and all the instances of C++ as well
- rebooted and ran the batch file mentioned above
- did a custom install. Only the Web Development Tools was installed. It succeeded and opened fine.
- did a Modify install and added the SQL data tools. No errors.
so far so good ..

Answer (score 0):

1. Before doing the reinstalling stage:

   A.Disable anti-virus or anti-spyware software.

   B. Clear this folder:
   **%windir%\Temp**

   and not only the %Temp% folder.
2. Run the installer as administrator.
3. Maybe I am wrong?
   but I have read [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3k0yjr/visual_studio_2015_not_installing_missing_or/) that we better also delete this folder:
   **C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18** before reinstall.

> After days of torment, here's the answer:
>   Delete or rename the following folder C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18\ to something like \backup-S-1-5-18\ ... Windows will re-create the folder with appropriate permissions and the installation will continue without error.
>   Cheers

What do you say?