# Visual Studio 2015 installation error(Win7 86x)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vsix, failed-installation, team-explorer

Windows 7 86x. Tried to install Visual Studio 2015 with web tools, but got this [error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiaD6.png)
Journal of installation(got from %TEMP%):

```
15.03.2016 18:45:00 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
15.03.2016 18:45:00 - -------------------------------------------
15.03.2016 18:45:02 - Initializing Uninstall...
15.03.2016 18:46:25 - Найден установленный продукт - Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
15.03.2016 18:46:25 - Подробности расширения...
15.03.2016 18:46:25 -   Identifier         : Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamExplorer.Extensions
15.03.2016 18:46:25 -   Name               : Team Foundation Team Explorer Extensions
15.03.2016 18:46:25 -   Author             : Microsoft
15.03.2016 18:46:25 -   Version            : 14.0.23102
15.03.2016 18:46:25 -   Description        : Team Foundation extensions for Team Explorer
15.03.2016 18:46:25 -   Locale             : en-US
15.03.2016 18:46:25 -   MoreInfoURL        : 
15.03.2016 18:46:25 -   InstalledByMSI     : False
15.03.2016 18:46:25 -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [0.0,2147483647.2147483647]
15.03.2016 18:46:25 - 
15.03.2016 18:46:25 -   Поддерживаемые продукты : 
15.03.2016 18:46:25 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntegratedShell
15.03.2016 18:46:25 -           Version : [14.0]
15.03.2016 18:46:25 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Express_All
15.03.2016 18:46:25 -           Version : [14.0]
15.03.2016 18:46:25 - 
15.03.2016 18:46:25 -   Ссылки             : 
15.03.2016 18:46:25 - System.MissingMethodException: Метод не найден: "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatus> Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.IInstallableExtension.get_InvalidCertificateInformation()".
   в VSIXInstaller.App.LogSignatureDetails(IExtension extension)
   в VSIXInstaller.App.LogExtensionDetails(IExtension extension)
   в VSIXInstaller.App.UninstallExtensionFromSKU(String vsixID, SupportedVSSKU sku)
   в VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeUninstall()
   в VSIXInstaller.App.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a similar problem to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855177/multiple-errors-installing-visual-studio-2015-community-edition/34008086) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889317/error-installing-visual-studio-2015-enterprise-update-1-with-team-explorer) except for the one using enterprise while you are using community.  I would work through either solution then try the other if the first doesn't work.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks :3

Comment: You're welcome.  Please mark my answer correct since it did.