# Windows 10 Visual Studio 2015 "Cannot find one ore more Components, please reinstall" Error

Tags: visual-studio, installation, windows-10

Im trying to install Visual Studio 2015 on my Windows 10 Machine for over a week now and i keep getting the same Error.

Im trying to install nothing but the default install and Visual C++.

I tried multiple ways to fix the error, mentioned in other tutorials, but none of them worked.
Those attemps include:

**devenv.exe /resetuserdata**

**devenv.exe /safemode**

**devenv.exe /resetsettings**

Looking at the security settings to see if they where wrong (they weren't)

Looking at the registry Value for the %Appdata% Key (was already set to the right value)

Lots and lots of reinstalls, repairs and i cleared all programms, used with VS once

i also collected the logs and shared them under 
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtU4BDC5eG5UhHX1S46oMnFPT3Ne

Comment: What does the install log tell you?

Comment: @KenWhite Where do i find the install log?

Comment: In the %Temp% directory. It will have a .log extension, and be dated the same date as when you last ran the installer.

Comment: @KenWhite i found it, is there any specific area in the file,i should focus on?

Comment: Oh, for Pete's sake! Yes. The parts that indicate errors or failures. Did you even look at it? Did you think you'd need to look at the lines that say *Succeeded* or *Complete* or *Passed*? Look at where the errors or failures start. Each line is date and time stamped.

Comment: @ErikSchulze, you can use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs. After using it, you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder then upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link here.

Comment: @Sara-MSFT okay,thanks for your advice , i uploaded the zip under https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtU4BDC5eG5UhHX1S46oMnFPT3Ne        i didnt find something when i looked in them, but i probably missed much

Comment: @ErikSchulze, from the log file, I found the error message like "ExecuteError: Package (MobileServicesConnectedServices_VS) failed: Error Message Id: 1722 ErrorMessage: There is a problem with this Windows Installer package....", please have a look at the solution that Anaksunaman provided in this similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36579844/visual-studio-2015-community-installation-failure/36855337#36855337

Comment: @Sara-MSFT ok,thanks ,i tried the steps in the guide and although they didn't fix the Problem, a clean Windows install and vs 2017 did it