# VS Community 2015 Setup Failed

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, installation

I was upgrading to VS 2015 Update 3, but got errors. I uninstalled VS 2015, restarted my system, and tried to install VS 2015 without updates but I get (apparently) the same errors.

[image: errors]

Anyone have an idea how to solve this issue?

PS: I'm not sure where to upload the log file, it has 1.6 MB.

---

**07/26/2016** What I've tried so far (in order):

- Deinstall VS 2015, reinstall
- Clean registry with CCleaner, reinstall
- [posting this question]
- Deleting the `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18` folder, reinstall
- Repairing the MSVC 2015 x64 and x86 redistributables, reinstall
- Removing the MSVC 2015 x64 and x86 redistributables, reinstall
- Installing VS 2015 from the .ISO without Update 3
- Installing VS 2015 from the .ISO without Update 3 in Window Safe Mode

Between the steps, I always had to deinstall VS 2015 again because even though the setup failed (and always with the same errors above), it received an entry in the Installed Programs.

The last lines of the log appear relevant:

```
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:47]i000: Setting string variable 'BundleResult' to value '0'
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:47]i319: Applied execute package: vstf_testExecCoreRes_enu, result: 0x0, restart: None
[281C:2810][2016-07-26T11:11:47]i325: Registering dependency: {04fa3a35-1f49-4510-8051-819cdc1e6e01} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.TestExecCoreRes_enu,v14, package: vstf_testExecCoreRes_enu
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:47]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin PackageId: vs_teamExplorerCore
[281C:2810][2016-07-26T11:11:47]i301: Applying execute package: vs_teamExplorerCore, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7932CD6F-86D3-3EE4-8A02-B954404D1FFC}v14.95.25118\packages\TeamExplorer\Core\vs_teamExplorerCore.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" USING_EXUIH="1"'
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (vs_teamExplorerCore) failed: Error Message Id: 1722 ErrorMessage: There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  
[281C:2810][2016-07-26T11:11:54]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
[281C:2810][2016-07-26T11:11:54]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: vs_teamExplorerCore MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 172871680  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 0
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x80070643 Msi Messages:There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.   Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i000: MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2147023293 (0x80070643), Error Message=There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  , Result Detail=, Vital=True, Package Action=Install, Package Id=vs_teamExplorerCore
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i000: Setting string variable 'BundleResult' to value '1603'
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i319: Applied execute package: vs_teamExplorerCore, result: 0x80070643, restart: None
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin PackageId: vs_teamExplorerCore
[281C:2810][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i318: Skipped rollback of package: vs_teamExplorerCore, action: Uninstall, already: Absent
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: vs_teamExplorerCore MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 0  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 0
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x0 Msi Messages:There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.   Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i000: MUX:  Reset execution Result
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i000: Setting string variable 'BundleResult' to value '1603'
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i319: Applied rollback package: vs_teamExplorerCore, result: 0x0, restart: None
[281C:2810][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i351: Removing cached package: vs_teamExplorerCore, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{7932CD6F-86D3-3EE4-8A02-B954404D1FFC}v14.95.25118\
[281C:2810][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{04fa3a35-1f49-4510-8051-819cdc1e6e01}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
[281C:2810][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{04fa3a35-1f49-4510-8051-819cdc1e6e01}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i000: MUX:  Apply Complete: Disk Space Used in bytes for Installation:  MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 5634158592  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 5379719168
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i000: MUX:  Free Disk Space after install:  SystemDrive C:\ 3702128640 bytes  AppDrive C:\ 3702128640 bytes
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i000: MUX:  Go to Finished page.
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i000: MUX:  Watson Bucketting Parameters
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i000: MUX:  P1 - vs_community
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i000: MUX:  P2 - 14.0.25123.00.00
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i000: MUX:  P3 - 14.0.25123
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i000: MUX:  P4 - Install
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i000: MUX:  P5 - vs_teamExplorerCore
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i000: MUX:  P6 - Install
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i000: MUX:  P7 - 0x80070643
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i000: MUX:  P8 - There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i000: MUX:  P9 - 
[2824:1078][2016-07-26T11:11:54]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070643, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Comment: It looks like it can't connect to Nuget to download the relevant packages.  Is there something in your dev environment that would stop the connection from working?  Is it being blocked by the firewall for instance?

Comment: redownload the installer and rerun

Comment: @kurakura88 Well, I certainly tried that. Just updated my question about what I tried.

Comment: @Delosdos Hm, I can't imagine it being the firewall. I did not change anything since I first installced VS 2015, which of course worked fine, until I tried upgrading to Update 3.

Comment: sorry for not helping much, did you do restart in between as well?

Comment: @kurakura88 No need to be sorry. :) Yes, I did. I also thought that installing in Safe Mode was worth a try, but it yield the same errors. :(

Answer (score 0):

The error message looks like similar with this: [Multiple Errors Installing Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855177/multiple-errors-installing-visual-studio-2015-community-edition)

TimVdG: The redistributable installer is messed up, it mixes up 64bit and 32bit dll's. You can check if you have this problem by looking at the vcruntime140.dll file size. Search your windows folder for "vcruntime140" you should see 4 files (64 and 32 bit in both release & debug versions). If any files have the same size, you need to run a repair on the redistributable.

Comment: Hi @Sara, thanks for the reply. I've already tried repairing the distributables, even deinstalling them. :(

Comment: Hi Niklas, have you tried other solutions in the above link, to be honest, the Process Monitor tool that mentioned in Ezh's blog is helpful to find the detail error information, but it is a little complex. Meanwhile, you can take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889317/error-installing-visual-studio-2015-enterprise-update-1-with-team-explorer and when you uninstall the VS, please remove or delete the related folders and registry keys.