# Visual Studio 2015 Installation Failed

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation

So i have been having problems downloading Visual Studio Community for a really long time, so i just tried to download it once again today, but still having problems. Here is the log from when the installation failed, i have no idea what to look for so i hope you guys can help me :)

Link: https://www.pastefs.com/pid/4018

*I couldnt use Pastebin because there was too much text.*

I am running Windows 7 btw.

Comment: The log has too many unnecessary details - It will be easier to answer, if you can also post what the setup mentioned. e.g. My VS installation _"failed" _ because there was no Internet connection, and only the Android NDK installation failed - the rest installed perfectly!

Comment: pastefs is an awesome service, it exceeds pastebin in many ways, so I think one should proudly use it instead of pastebin

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the error message in your log, I recommend you use the command: vs_community.exe /uninstall /force to forcibly uninstall the VS or directly uninstall the VS community 2015 item under Control Panel—Programs and Features then rename or delete the relevant folders and registry keys like this: [Error Installing Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 1 with Team Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889317/error-installing-visual-studio-2015-enterprise-update-1-with-team-explorer)

After that, reboot your computer, download a healthy ISO file of VS community 2015 with update 3 and use it to install. Before installation, make use your windows update is up-to-date, disable anti-virus and clean up the %temp% folder, then run the installer as administrator.

Meanwhile, I found you use the parameter ‘/CustomInstallPath’ to set the installation folder to the folder ‘G:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Studio 2015’, usually the VS should install to the system drive and you should choose the default installation during the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try repairing 2015 VC redistributables and then restarting Visual Studio installer base on TimVdG's answer in this question: [Multiple Errors Installing Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855177/multiple-errors-installing-visual-studio-2015-community-edition/33881460#33881460).

> After the failed install you have to repair the 2015 vc
>   redistributables and restart the visual studio installer.
>
> The redistributable installer is messed up, it mixes up 64bit and
>   32bit dll's. You can check if you have this problem by looking at the
>   vcruntime140.dll file size. Search your windows folder for
>   "vcruntime140" you should see 4 files (64 and 32 bit in both release &
>   debug versions). If any files have the same size, you need to run a
>   repair on the redistributable.
>
> On my system the 32 bit dll is 83,3KB, the 64 bit is 86,6KB ( release
>   versions )

More detailed information is here: [Investigation of a setup error of the Visual Studio of 2015](http://developers-club.com/posts/271809/).