# Assistance Installing VS community 2015

Tags: visual-studio, installation

I need help installing Vs community 2015. It seems that all of the packages installs fail and after a look at the log file it seems that the installer has trouble installing the .msi files. I know this is a noob question but I'm just getting into this stuff

THX

-R

Log: https://onedrive.live.com?v=TextFileEditor&id=1E07E777E1EC9722!4853&cid=1E07E777E1EC9722&parId=1E07E777E1EC9722!2532

Screen Shot: https://gyazo.com/8a6f775e3a8e478ea4ebf4c06e355810

Comment: Hi Ricky, does your issue is solved or not through the following reply? If not, I have checked you shared log and it is unavailable, you can use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather it, then you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder and share it. Meanwhile, you can also take a look at this 2 similar issue: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsnetsetup/2016/05/06/error-1722-there-is-a-problem-with-this-windows-installer-package/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889317/error-installing-visual-studio-2015-enterprise-update-1-with-team-explorer

Comment: @Ricky Gonce, what about this issue? Please let me know the latest information in your side？

Answer (score 1):

Please check that whether it is related to the VS2015 VC redistributables:

[Multiple Errors Installing Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855177/multiple-errors-installing-visual-studio-2015-community-edition)

Different community members met the same issue before, the most possible reason is that it is related to the VC redistributables, you could uninstall it and re-install the VS again.