# Removing old versions of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, uninstallation

So, I now only have **Visual Studio 2017** on my PC. I removed Visual Studio 2015.

Yet, I have all these folders:

[image: Visual Studio Files]

For example:

[image: Visual Studio 8]

And for others:

Visual Studio **11.0**:

```
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 7810-74A5

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0

22/08/2016  14:55    <DIR>          .
22/08/2016  14:55    <DIR>          ..
22/08/2016  14:55                 0 extensions.configurationchanged
05/07/2016  09:33    <DIR>          VC
               1 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\UnitTest\WindowsPhone\Include

05/07/2016  09:33    <DIR>          .
05/07/2016  09:33    <DIR>          ..
03/08/2015  18:00            19,323 CppUnitTest.h
03/08/2015  18:00            26,741 CppUnitTestAssert.h
03/08/2015  18:00             2,030 CppUnitTestCommon.h
03/08/2015  18:00               384 CppUnitTestException.h
03/08/2015  18:00             1,152 CppUnitTestLogger.h
               5 File(s)         49,630 bytes

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\UnitTest\WindowsPhone\Lib

05/07/2016  09:33    <DIR>          .
05/07/2016  09:33    <DIR>          ..
05/07/2016  09:33    <DIR>          arm
11/06/2015  13:41            14,508 Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.lib
               1 File(s)         14,508 bytes

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\UnitTest\WindowsPhone\Lib\arm

05/07/2016  09:33    <DIR>          .
05/07/2016  09:33    <DIR>          ..
11/06/2015  13:41            14,508 Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.lib
               1 File(s)         14,508 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               8 File(s)         78,646 bytes
              20 Dir(s)  16,162,922,496 bytes free
```

Visual Studio **12.0**:

```
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 7810-74A5

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0

19/09/2016  15:07    <DIR>          .
19/09/2016  15:07    <DIR>          ..
19/09/2016  15:07    <DIR>          Common7
22/08/2016  14:55                 0 extensions.configurationchanged
05/07/2016  09:33    <DIR>          VC
               1 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger

19/09/2016  15:07    <DIR>          .
19/09/2016  15:07    <DIR>          ..
10/10/2015  21:34           895,648 msdia120.dll
               1 File(s)        895,648 bytes

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\UnitTest\Include

05/07/2016  09:33    <DIR>          .
05/07/2016  09:33    <DIR>          ..
20/09/2015  16:20            19,323 CppUnitTest.h
20/09/2015  16:20            26,741 CppUnitTestAssert.h
20/09/2015  16:20             2,030 CppUnitTestCommon.h
20/09/2015  16:20               384 CppUnitTestException.h
20/09/2015  16:20             1,152 CppUnitTestLogger.h
               5 File(s)         49,630 bytes

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\UnitTest\Lib

05/07/2016  09:33    <DIR>          .
05/07/2016  09:33    <DIR>          ..
05/07/2016  09:33    <DIR>          amd64
05/07/2016  09:33    <DIR>          arm
20/06/2016  13:04            14,508 Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.lib
               1 File(s)         14,508 bytes

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\UnitTest\Lib\amd64

05/07/2016  09:33    <DIR>          .
05/07/2016  09:33    <DIR>          ..
20/06/2016  12:33            14,786 Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.lib
               1 File(s)         14,786 bytes

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\UnitTest\Lib\arm

05/07/2016  09:33    <DIR>          .
05/07/2016  09:33    <DIR>          ..
20/06/2016  12:17            14,636 Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.lib
               1 File(s)         14,636 bytes

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\UnitTest\WindowsPhone\Include

05/07/2016  09:33    <DIR>          .
05/07/2016  09:33    <DIR>          ..
03/08/2015  18:00            19,323 CppUnitTest.h
03/08/2015  18:00            26,741 CppUnitTestAssert.h
03/08/2015  18:00             2,030 CppUnitTestCommon.h
03/08/2015  18:00               384 CppUnitTestException.h
03/08/2015  18:00             1,152 CppUnitTestLogger.h
               5 File(s)         49,630 bytes

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\UnitTest\WindowsPhone\Lib

05/07/2016  09:33    <DIR>          .
05/07/2016  09:33    <DIR>          ..
05/07/2016  09:33    <DIR>          arm
20/06/2016  13:04            14,508 Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.lib
               1 File(s)         14,508 bytes

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\UnitTest\WindowsPhone\Lib\arm

05/07/2016  09:33    <DIR>          .
05/07/2016  09:33    <DIR>          ..
20/06/2016  12:17            14,508 Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.lib
               1 File(s)         14,508 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
              17 File(s)      1,067,854 bytes
              41 Dir(s)  16,162,332,672 bytes free
```

The **14.0** folder has over **3 GB** of data in it.

The **.Old** folder has about 15 MB of data in it.

**Visual Studio 2017** is installed in:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community

I just seem to have a lot of files here and appreciate some advice.

Thank you.

## Update

Looking here:

[image: VS Versions]

So we have 2 files from Visual Studio 2005 which I have never installed (in years).

We have a handful of files from Visual Studio 2012 which I have never owned.

We have a few files from Visual Studio 2013. Now, I did own that (paid for it).

Then, despite the fact I uninstalled  VS2015 there are GB's of data still there and no actual executable.

I think the .old folder is a past attempt at the 2017 version when I had problems before. So I think that is redundant.

## Update 2

I thought I would just see what the **Control Panel** indicated as still installed.

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2005:

[image: Control Panel 2005]

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2008:

[image: Control panel 2010]

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2012:

[image: Control Panel 2012]

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2013:

[image: Control Panel 2013]

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2015:

[image: Control Panel 2015]

Comment: Maybe try the steps in [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt720585.aspx). tl;dr: *run `vs_enterprise.exe /uninstall /force`, which will remove Visual Studio and most of the core components that are left behind in a default uninstallation*.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Thanks. But as you can see, some of those folders have 2 DLL files in, or a small handful of CPP files.

Comment: Except dirts leftover by VS installer, you might also have other apps (depending on VS Shell) installed, which hold such folders. Simply ignore them if you can.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, to uninstall the remaining or shared components of the VS, you can have a look at this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2015/07/14/how-to-install-visual-studio-to-another-directory-when-a-pre-release-is-installed/ and use the PowerShell command with different GUIDs to remove. For the VS 2015 version, you can manually delete some folders that Brian Swart mentioned in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889317/error-installing-visual-studio-2015-enterprise-update-1-with-team-explorer