# Visual Studio Community 2015 not installing - Multiple errors during installation

Tags: visual-studio, azure, team-explorer, visual-studio-2015

First of all, I know there are similar problems, but none of the answers work for me. I am trying to install `Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 1` via `Web Installer`on my **Windows 10 Single Language 64-bit** PC.

**The Errors (Log File [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8UizUpBrF1YQ0Y3ZVh6YzhQTU0), interesting part of Log at end) -**

- Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2015 -> Fatal Error During Installation
- Microsoft NuGet Visual Studio 2015 -> Package Failed
- Microsoft Visual Studio Connected Services -> Packages Failed
- Azure AD Authentication Connected Services -> Packages Failed
- Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Connected Service -> Package Failed
- Microsoft Azure Storage Connected Service -> Packages Failed
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Office365 -> Package Failed

**Solutions I have tried -**

- Clearing Temp Files, ProgramData folder (As given on Microsoft common errors and workarounds)
- Installing Express editions (Got same errors)
- Repairing Visual C++ Redistributables 2015 64 bit and 32 bit (Restarted PC after repairing each one)
- Repairing Visual C++ Redistributables 2005-2015 64 bit and 32 bit (Restarted PC after repairing all together)
- Repairing Visual Studio over 1000+ times with every solution (Got same errors everytime)

**Some Extra Info -**

- Don't suggest me to use ISO installer, as -  1) I don't have enough
  internet to download all of the ISO at once, and 2) The other
  questions all say that if the Web one doesn't work then ISO one
  doesn't work too.
- I searched for `vcruntime140.dll` after repairing but the files are of different sizes than given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855177/multiple-errors-installing-visual-studio-2015-community-edition).
- I don't have `Office 365` so I don't need that.
- I also don't need Azure or Team Explorer or the other things of which I get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found there is a way to clean uninstall all Visual Studio components
https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller

I faced such problem before, where removing all Visual C++ Redistributables and Regsitry does not helps.
I almost end up with re-installing my windows...
But luckily, i found this app, it saved me from alot of trouble.

credits to tobyhu87 @ github

Answer (score 0):

Finally found an answer -

1) Delete ALL Visual C++ Redistributables and Visual Studio.

2) Go to Regedit and delete all registries related to Visual Studio.

3) Install only Visual C++ 2015 x64 and x86 Redistributables, then install Visual Studio.

Comment: Just don't mess around with the registries too much. I kinda nuked my registries and had to reinstall Windows. Oops.

Answer (score 0):

turn on Windows Update in Services 
run enter Services.msc