# Where is the Visual C++ Update 2 Runtime

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, runtime

Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 has been released for 7 days. Where can I download the Visual C++ Update 2 runtime so I can run the applications compiled with Visual C++ 2015 Update 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [download](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads/Results?pid=2082)

[image]

> Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable installs run-time components
>   of Visual C++ libraries. These components are required to run C++
>   applications that are developed using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and
>   link dynamically to Visual C++ libraries. The packages can be used to
>   run such applications on a computer even if it does not have Visual
>   Studio 2015 installed. These packages also install run-time components
>   of C Runtime (CRT), Standard C++, MFC, C++ AMP, and OpenMP libraries.
>   Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable includes bug fixes to the
>   runtime DLLs and also the latest versions for KB 2999226.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: @smwikipedia thx, I've updated the link to the 2015 Update 3 Runtime

Answer (score 1):

There are two files in the Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 VC++ Redistributable package.

- vc_redist.x64.exe (v14.0.23918.0).
  https://download.microsoft.com/download/0/5/0/0504B211-6090-48B1-8DEE-3FF879C29968/vc_redist.x64.exe
- vc_redist.x86.exe (v14.0.23918.0).
  https://download.microsoft.com/download/0/5/0/0504B211-6090-48B1-8DEE-3FF879C29968/vc_redist.x86.exe

For those that care, the x64 version sets the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\VC\Servicing\14.0\RuntimeMinimum\UpdateVersion (REG_SZ)
```

to the value "14.0.23918".

For the x86 version, check for the existence of the registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{2e085fd2-a3e4-4b39-8e10-6b8d35f55244}
```

If it exists, the update is already installed.