# Multiple errors when installing Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio

So, I downloaded VS Professional and when I went to install it, I got the following errors:

```
Team Explorer for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 : Fatal error during installation.
Microsoft NuGet - Visual Studio 2015 : Package failed.
Microsoft Visual Studio Connected Services : Package failed.
Azure AD Authentication Connected Service : Package failed.
Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Connected Service : Package failed.
Microsoft Azure Storage Connected Service : Package failed.
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Office365 : Package failed.
```

I tried every solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855177/multiple-errors-installing-visual-studio-2015-community-edition) other question (besides a clean windows install), but none of them worked. Any ideas?

Edit: [Link](http://www.kazesenoue.moe/uploads/log.txt) to the log file generated by the installer. Ps.: It's a 1.3MB file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I managed to solve these issues by downloading Revo Uninstaller and uninstalling every C++ Redistributable on my computer, and letting VS install the proper ones.