# Error installing Visual Studio 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installation

I'm trying to install Visual Studio 2015, and receive the following error:

[image]

Additionally, here is some of the input from my log file:

```
[3218:039C][2016-07-07T11:34:22]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed to move verified file to complete payload path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{79750C81-714E-45F2-B5DE-42DEF00687B8}v14.0.25420\packages\BuildTools_MSBuild_amd64\BuildTools1.cab
[3218:039C][2016-07-07T11:34:22]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed to cache payload: cabDB4A67A526A8A2A72A590422CCE486F7
....
[26EC:10D4][2016-07-07T11:34:22]e349: Application requested retry of payload: cabDB4A67A526A8A2A72A590422CCE486F7, encountered error: 0x80070002. Retrying...
....
[3218:3244][2016-07-07T11:35:28]e000: Error 0x80070643: Process returned error: 0x643
[3218:3244][2016-07-07T11:35:28]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute EXE package.
....
[26EC:2154][2016-07-07T11:35:28]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
....
[26EC:10D4][2016-07-07T11:35:30]e000: Error 0x80070642: UX aborted on download progress.
[26EC:10D4][2016-07-07T11:35:30]e000: Error 0x80070642: UX aborted on cache progress.
[26EC:10D4][2016-07-07T11:35:30]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed while reading from internet and writing to: D:\Users\AFREYM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\11\{79b486b9-c5f0-4096-a00c-8351f59587c2}\cab99BE860BD8B3416F4ABD18F406FCF4BD
[26EC:10D4][2016-07-07T11:35:31]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed to download URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12514&pver=Dev14&sbp=d14rel&plcid=0x409&clcid=0x409&ar=25420.01.00&sar=S80_RCPrep&o1=BF1A4C380EC691D332B21FC3E6591BE0E9B4C316
[26EC:10D4][2016-07-07T11:35:31]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed attempt to download URL: 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12514&pver=Dev14&sbp=d14rel&plcid=0x409&clcid=0x409&ar=25420.01.00&sar=S80_RCPrep&o1=BF1A4C380EC691D332B21FC3E6591BE0E9B4C316' to: 'D:\Users\AFREYM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\11\{79b486b9-c5f0-4096-a00c-8351f59587c2}\cab99BE860BD8B3416F4ABD18F406FCF4BD'
[26EC:10D4][2016-07-07T11:35:31]i000: MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2147023294 (0x80070642), Error Message=, Result Detail=, Vital=True, Package Action=Download_WinInet, Package Id=vs_communitycoreres
[26EC:10D4][2016-07-07T11:35:31]e000: Error 0x80070642: Failed to acquire payload from: 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12514&pver=Dev14&sbp=d14rel&plcid=0x409&clcid=0x409&ar=25420.01.00&sar=S80_RCPrep&o1=BF1A4C380EC691D332B21FC3E6591BE0E9B4C316' to working path: 'D:\Users\AFREYM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\11\{79b486b9-c5f0-4096-a00c-8351f59587c2}\cab99BE860BD8B3416F4ABD18F406FCF4BD'
[26EC:10D4][2016-07-07T11:35:31]e313: Failed to acquire payload: cab99BE860BD8B3416F4ABD18F406FCF4BD to working path: D:\Users\AFREYM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\11\{79b486b9-c5f0-4096-a00c-8351f59587c2}\cab99BE860BD8B3416F4ABD18F406FCF4BD, error: 0x80070642.
```

From a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855177/multiple-errors-installing-visual-studio-2015-community-edition), I did solutions number 1-3 to no avail, and tried for 5 repairing the redistributables was unfortunately not an option given. This seems somewhat like a caching issue - any ideas?

Comment: Try to uninstall .NET if it shows up, then uninstall the framework, then reboot, then reinstall the framework then reinstall .NET. Please provide results after you try this.

Comment: I have multiple frameworks that I can uninstall, purge them all?