# How install Visual Studio 2015 community on windows 7 SP1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have Windows 7 x64 SP1 with all nessesery updates: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5842. When I try to install VS 2015 Community after istall I can't start programs on my OS Windows, error: 0xc0000005.

On https://www.microsoft.com there is information that VS 2015 Community can be install on Windows 7 x64 SP1.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/q/33855177/11683 help?

Comment: Or do you mean that you install VS successfully, but then you can't start any other programs?

Comment: Yes, install pass successfull, then error to sturt all programs and VS 2015 as well.

Comment: About error 0xc0000005:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2718841

Answer (score 0):

As per Microsoft:-

This issue occurs because of a race condition. When a thread tries to close the handle to an object that is being destroyed, the operation fails.

you can find the hotfix also here:-https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/2718841

Comment: Does not help. Error continue.