# Few warnings after Installing VS2015 Community Edition with ISO

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation

I finished installing VS2015 on windows 7, 64-bit, but have the following warnings:

[image]

[Note that the error code of the last one is 0x80070490, too].

It doesn't seem to be a similar case to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855177/multiple-errors-installing-visual-studio-2015-community-edition/33881460), and I couldn't find any helpful help out there. Any help is welcomed.

Comment: does your issue is solved or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error code ‘0x80091007’ means the hash value is not correct, you need to check the integrity of the ISO file. You can use [the fciv.exe tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2011/03/25/verify-the-iso-checksum-for-visual-studio-2010-service-pack-1-before-installing/) to check the SHA1 value of the ISO, the expected value comes from [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/productinfo/vs2015-sha-vs), any discrepancy means the ISO is corrupted.

Since the update ‘KB3165756’ install failed, you can go to [KB3165756](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt752379.aspx) and manually download the installer and save it to a new, empty folder, then use it to install.

Meanwhile, in case the internet connection is not good on your local that caused this issue, you can try to create an offline installer package using the /layout switch, for the detail information, you can also find from the above KB3165756 document link.

Comment: Don't need separate tool check SHA1. In PowerShell, run `Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA1 -Path ...`

Comment: The ISO checksum is correct. Running the installation of KB3165756 finished without errors - does it mean everything is fine?

Comment: @HelterSkelter, does the VS 2015 can normal open and create different project type to develop? If so, the installation should be successful.

Comment: Yes, it can. Thanks!