# Multiple Errors During Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition on my pc, but I keep getting the same errors, can anyone help?

- Team Explorer for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 CTP1 : Fatal error during installation.
- Microsoft NuGet - Visual Studio 2015 : Package failed.
- Microsoft Visual Studio Connected Services : Package failed.
- Azure AD Authentication Connected Service : Package failed.
- Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Connected Service : Package failed.
- Microsoft Azure Storage Connected Service : Package failed.
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Office365 : Package failed.
- Microsoft ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools - Visual Studio 2015 - ENU
  : Package failed.

Answer (score 0):

Installation package may be corrupted.
Source a new copy and install again.

Try installing 'As Administrator'

Try running windows update and installing any missing updates.

Or, first look up your question and read the answer here:
[Multiple Errors Installing Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855177/multiple-errors-installing-visual-studio-2015-community-edition?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

turn on Windows Update in Services 
press windows + r enter Services.msc