# Visual studio 2015 Setup Error: Update 3 CPI1 Team Explorer Language Pack - ENU

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installation

I've tried Downloading Visual studio 2015 enterprise on my macbook through parallel desktop on windows 10... I've tried everything but I just can't get it to work somehow... I've tried every kind of solution on the internet but I still can't get it to work... So I hoped that someone here might be able to help me with this problem by looking at the log.. Since I dont know what the problem might be!

```
[This is the error][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0GtK.png



[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:02]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:02]i000: Setting string variable 'BundleResult' to value '0'
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:02]i319: Applied execute package: vs_teamExplorerCore, result: 0x0, restart: None
[0A24:04D0][2017-01-07T19:53:02]i325: Registering dependency: {e2ccc441-0cf4-43f1-9306-c3c1c6cd4ce3} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.TeamExplorerCore,v14, package: vs_teamExplorerCore
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:02]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin PackageId: vs_teamExplorerCoreRes_enu
[0A24:04D0][2017-01-07T19:53:02]i301: Applying execute package: vs_teamExplorerCoreRes_enu, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{FFA8B646-066E-34A4-8168-C410DAFA631F}v14.98.25331\packages\TeamExplorer\enu\vs_teamExplorerCoreRes_enu.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" USING_EXUIH="1"'
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:03]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (vs_teamExplorerCoreRes_enu) failed: Error Message Id: 1606 ErrorMessage: Could not access network location \\psf\Home\Desktop\.
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:03]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (vs_teamExplorerCoreRes_enu) failed: Error Message Id: 1606 ErrorMessage: Could not access network location \\psf\Home\Desktop\.
[0A24:04D0][2017-01-07T19:53:03]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
[0A24:04D0][2017-01-07T19:53:03]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:03]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:03]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: vs_teamExplorerCoreRes_enu MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 81920  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 81920
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:03]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x80070643 Msi Messages:Could not access network location \\psf\Home\Desktop\. Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:03]i000: MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2147023293 (0x80070643), Error Message=Could not access network location \\psf\Home\Desktop\., Result Detail=, Vital=True, Package Action=Install, Package Id=vs_teamExplorerCoreRes_enu
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:03]i000: Setting string variable 'BundleResult' to value '1603'
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:03]i319: Applied execute package: vs_teamExplorerCoreRes_enu, result: 0x80070643, restart: None
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:03]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:03]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin PackageId: vs_teamExplorerCoreRes_enu
[0A24:04D0][2017-01-07T19:53:03]i318: Skipped rollback of package: vs_teamExplorerCoreRes_enu, action: Uninstall, already: Absent
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:03]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: vs_teamExplorerCoreRes_enu MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 0  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 0
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:03]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x0 Msi Messages:Could not access network location \\psf\Home\Desktop\. Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:03]i000: MUX:  Reset execution Result
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:03]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:03]i000: Setting string variable 'BundleResult' to value '1603'
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:03]i319: Applied rollback package: vs_teamExplorerCoreRes_enu, result: 0x0, restart: None
[0A24:04D0][2017-01-07T19:53:03]i351: Removing cached package: vs_teamExplorerCoreRes_enu, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{FFA8B646-066E-34A4-8168-C410DAFA631F}v14.98.25331\
[0A24:04D0][2017-01-07T19:53:03]i326: Removed dependency: {e2ccc441-0cf4-43f1-9306-c3c1c6cd4ce3} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.TeamExplorerCore,v14, package vs_teamExplorerCore
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:03]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin PackageId: vs_teamExplorerCore
[0A24:04D0][2017-01-07T19:53:03]i301: Applying rollback package: vs_teamExplorerCore, action: Uninstall, path: (null), arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" USING_EXUIH="1"'
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:13]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: vs_teamExplorerCore MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 1392640  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 0
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:13]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x0 Msi Messages:0 Result Detail:RollbackCleanup Restart:None
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:13]i000: MUX:  Reset execution Result
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:13]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:13]i000: Setting string variable 'BundleResult' to value '1603'
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:13]i319: Applied rollback package: vs_teamExplorerCore, result: 0x0, restart: None
[0A24:04D0][2017-01-07T19:53:13]i351: Removing cached package: vs_teamExplorerCore, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{C0402801-37B7-30B1-A678-AE3E73E4C4F6}v14.98.25331\
[0A24:04D0][2017-01-07T19:53:13]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{e2ccc441-0cf4-43f1-9306-c3c1c6cd4ce3}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
[0A24:04D0][2017-01-07T19:53:13]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{e2ccc441-0cf4-43f1-9306-c3c1c6cd4ce3}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:13]i000: MUX:  Apply Complete: Disk Space Used in bytes for Installation:  MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 417275904  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 185724928
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:13]i000: MUX:  Free Disk Space after install:  SystemDrive C:\ 46879289344 bytes  AppDrive C:\ 46879289344 bytes
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:13]i000: MUX:  Go to Finished page.
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:13]i000: MUX:  Watson Bucketting Parameters
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:13]i000: MUX:  P1 - vs_enterprise
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:13]i000: MUX:  P2 - 14.0.25420.01.00
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:13]i000: MUX:  P3 - 14.0.25420
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:13]i000: MUX:  P4 - Install
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:13]i000: MUX:  P5 - vs_teamExplorerCoreRes_enu
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:13]i000: MUX:  P6 - Install
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:13]i000: MUX:  P7 - 0x80070643
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:13]i000: MUX:  P8 - Could not access network location \\psf\Home\Desktop\.
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:13]i000: MUX:  P9 - 
[17A4:03AC][2017-01-07T19:53:13]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070643, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Comment: Solutions I've tried: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs-knownissues/vs2015-update3
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855177/multiple-errors-installing-visual-studio-2015-community-edition/33881460

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the error message “Error Message Id: 1606 ErrorMessage: Could not access network location \psf\Home\Desktop\”, you can have a look at [this similar issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b0d9c4e5-8fd8-4ac1-9261-8398234fe9f5/ms-vs-2015-rc-install-error?forum=vssetup) with the same error message and try with following workaround:

**Hale**: I solved by running the vm in parallels isolation mode, rebooting then running the vs install again.

**Anystone**: This fixed it for me - re-installed Win 10 preview and ensured that the Parallels settings were such that it wasn't mapping the user directories (music/documents/downloads/desktop etc to the Mac side). I then installed it from the ISO no problem.

This issue is about the Paralles, you can also check [this related error issue](http://kb.parallels.com/en/114310).

Comment: Cheers! this helped me! I thought at first it might have been about the iso files or some missing updates... But it was the parallel after all!...
Thanks a bunch!