# Issues installing Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio

I have been trying to install visual studio 2015 so I can install the core tools from here [Core Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2015)

Every time I install Visual Studio 2015 I get errors, see below screen shot, with packages not installing and these subsequently prevent me from installing the core tools.

[image]

I get these errors in both the community and professional versions. The install log shows the following errors for each of the packages shown below

> [18C4:2618][2017-02-07T13:17:37]e000: Error 0x800b0003: Failed authenticode verification of payload: C:\ProgramData\Package
>
> Cache.unverified\nugetvs
> [18C4:2618][2017-02-07T13:17:37]e000: Error 0x800b0003: Failed to verify signature of payload: nugetvs

Any ideas why this verification would fail?

I did see [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855177/multiple-errors-installing-visual-studio-2015-community-editionhttp://) but the solution there didn't help here and the log messages are different

Comment: Maybe a network/proxy error?

Comment: 0x800b0003 = TRUST_E_SUBJECT_FORM_UNKNOWN = "The form specified for the subject is not one supported or known by the specified trust provider." which windows version do you use? is windows up to date?

Comment: Windows 7. Our machines gets updated weekly so yeah it should be up to date. I was thinking it was something to do with certs being out of date but they look ok

Comment: run windowsupdate and look if your windows is really up 2 date

Comment: The machine is on a company network and controlled by systems. I imagine updates are the issue but can't be sure. I moved to a windows 10 VM and it works fine now. Thanks for your help