# setup failed visual studio 2015 on windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installation, windows-10

Please help me,
I want to install visual studio 2015 on windows 10, but I getting problem again and again. 
[that error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57Q1P.png)

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you using?

Comment: Please use tool: https://aka.ms/vscollect to review the logs %temp%\vslogs.zip, we need to analyze the detailed log messages. You could also refer to this blog:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsnetsetup/2016/05/06/error-1722-there-is-a-problem-with-this-windows-installer-package/, and make sure that whether it is related to the Studio 5000 View Designer or others, you could share the vslogs.zip file using one drive.

Comment: I using Windows 10 Home version

Comment: @Ishaq, please check this similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855177/multiple-errors-installing-visual-studio-2015-community-edition/33881460