# Can I install vs 2008 in vs 2015 installed windows 10 machine?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2008, windows-10

According to some requirement I need to install VS 2008 in VS 2015 installed windows 10 OS machine.Do I need to uninstall VS 2015?

Comment: Historically you could always install different versions of VS side by side.  Whether or not VS2008 works on Windows 10 I am not sure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Errors Installing Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855177/multiple-errors-installing-visual-studio-2015-community-edition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to uninstall later version of Visual Studio to install earlier version of Visual Studio. So, you should be able to install Visual Studio 2008 even if you have Visual studio 2015 already installed.