# Fatal error while installing visual studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

Screenshot of the error

[image]

The error reads 
Setup Failed!
Install Cannot continue because some required components failed.

And in the problems,

Team Explorer for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 CTP1
-Fatal error during installation.

I tried installing Visual Studio 2015 Community edition many times but getting the same error. Everytime while re-installing , I made sure all the temp files of previous installation were removed properly.

Looking for a solution as soon as possible.

Comment: The log file should give you more specific information about the failure. The dialog in your screenshot has a link that will open it up.

Comment: I believe this is more a question for the superuser forum: it's not about development, but about installing a tool.

Comment: @kettch   [0084:20D0][2018-01-30T12:13:59]i000: MUX:  P5 - vs_teamExplorerCore
[0084:20D0][2018-01-30T12:13:59]i000: MUX:  P6 - Install
[0084:20D0][2018-01-30T12:13:59]i000: MUX:  P7 - 0x80070643
[0084:20D0][2018-01-30T12:13:59]i000: MUX:  P8 - There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  
[0084:20D0][2018-01-30T12:13:59]i000: MUX:  P9 - 
[0084:20D0][2018-01-30T12:13:59]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070643, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No

Comment: What OS and Service Pack version are you using?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Windows 10 version 1703 (OS Build 15063.786)

Comment: Have you considered just installing VS 2017 Community Edition instead? According to the [known issues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs-knownissues/vs2015-update3) the "CTP1" part of the display string is incorrect, so it's really the final version. That said, VS 2017 Community is available and does everything VS 2015 does but better.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some possible workarounds.

1. Try to re install
2. Try to repair if the first step didn't work.
3. Try disabling your anti virus and install again
4. Make sure you are running the actual executable file (64 or 34 bit)

You can also get some more information from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855177/multiple-errors-installing-visual-studio-2015-community-edition). You may be able to find some common error details [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/3039361/common-issues-in-visual-studio-2015-setup).

Comment: Log File : [0084:20D0][2018-01-30T12:13:59]i000: MUX:  P5 - vs_teamExplorerCore
[0084:20D0][2018-01-30T12:13:59]i000: MUX:  P6 - Install
[0084:20D0][2018-01-30T12:13:59]i000: MUX:  P7 - 0x80070643
[0084:20D0][2018-01-30T12:13:59]i000: MUX:  P8 - There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  
[0084:20D0][2018-01-30T12:13:59]i000: MUX:  P9 - 
[0084:20D0][2018-01-30T12:13:59]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070643, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No

Comment: got the same error when I tried following each and every step mentioned.